# Echo Javascript with IF-ELSE in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I'm new to PHP and I have a problem about my Javascript is not working for now.

Here is my codes so far

```
    <?php

        $email = $_POST["App_Email"];
        $password = $_POST["App_Password"];
        $name = $_POST["App_Name"];
        $lName = $_POST["App_LName"];
        $gender = $_POST["App_Gender"];
        $birthday = $_POST["App_Birthday"];
        $nationality = $_POST["App_Nationality"];
        $telNumber = $_POST["App_Tel"];
        $address = $_POST["App_Address"];
        $district = $_POST["App_District"];
        $city = $_POST["App_City"];
        $zipcode = $_POST["App_Zipcode"];

        $repass = $_POST["RePassword"];

        $message = "";
        if($email == ""  or $password == "" or $repass == "" or $name == "" or $lName == "" or $birthday == "" or $nationality == "" or $telNumber == "" or $address == "" or $district == "" or $city == "" or $zipcode == "" ){
            $message = "FILL ALL";
        }
        elseif($repass != $password){
            $message = "NOT MATCH"; 
        }

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';


    if($message == "FILL ALL"){
        echo 'alert("Please fill in all provided field(s).")';
        echo 'location.href = "registration.php"';
        return;
    }
    else if($message == "NOT MATCH"){
        echo 'alert("Your confirmation password is not match with your password.")';
        echo 'location.href = "registration.php"';
        return;
    }


echo '</script>';

?>

<br><br>

<form method="POST" action="confirm-registration.php">

Name : <?php echo $_POST["App_Name"]; ?><br><br>
Lastname : <?php echo $_POST["App_LName"]; ?><br><br>
Gender :  <?php echo $_POST["App_Gender"]; ?><br><br>
Date of birth : <?php echo $_POST["App_Birthday"]; ?> <br><br>
Nationality : <?php echo $_POST["App_Nationality"]; ?><br><br>
Tel. : <?php echo $_POST["App_Tel"]; ?><br><br>
Address : <?php echo $_POST["App_Address"]; ?><br><br>
District : <?php echo $_POST["App_District"]; ?><br><br>
City : <?php echo $_POST["App_City"]; ?><br><br>
Zipcode : <?php echo $_POST["App_Zipcode"]; ?><br><br>

<input type='hidden' name='App_Email' value='<?=$email?>'>
<input type='hidden' name='App_Password' value='<?=$password?>'>
<input type='hidden' name='App_Name' value='<?=$name?>'>
<input type='hidden' name='App_LName' value='<?=$lName?>'>
<input type='hidden' name='App_Gender' value='<?=$gender?>'>
<input type='hidden' name='App_Birthday' value='<?=$birthday?>'>
<input type='hidden' name='App_Nationality' value='<?=$nationality?>'>
<input type='hidden' name='App_Tel' value='<?=$telNumber?>'>
<input type='hidden' name='App_Address' value='<?=$address?>'>
<input type='hidden' name='App_District' value='<?=$district?>'>
<input type='hidden' name='App_City' value='<?=$city?>'>
<input type='hidden' name='App_Zipcode' value='<?=$zipcode?>'>

<button onClick="history.back()";> Back </button>  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Confirm">
</form>
```

From the codes above, my result in this page is just a plain white page.

When I tried to test the not completed the form case and password is not matched. But no alert is pop-up. Even all fields from the form page is inserted, this page stills plain white.

Please help.

Comment: Why `return` in `if`?

Comment: You know the purpose of  `return`, don't you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Various problems in your code:

1. Missing `isset()`. Turn on your error reporting, you will find numerous `Notice: Undefined index` errors
2. Why `return` in `if`? Is it a function?
3. Missing `;` in your Javascript:

   ```
   if($message == "FILL ALL"){
       echo 'alert("Please fill in all provided field(s).");';
       echo 'location.href = "registration.php";';

   }
   else if($message == "NOT MATCH"){
       echo 'alert("Your confirmation password is not match with your password.");';
       echo 'location.href = "registration.php";';
   }
   ```
4. All your HTML fields are `hidden`, where does the user enter values?

Comment: for (4) it is from the last page. i didn't post my codes

Answer (score 0):

Use ; inside echo statements

```
if($message == "FILL ALL"){
  echo 'alert("Please fill in all provided field(s).");';
  echo 'location.href = "registration.php";';
}
else if($message == "NOT MATCH"){
   echo 'alert("Your confirmation password is not match with your password.");';
   echo 'location.href = "registration.php";';
}
```